# Restrict access to page - PHP

Tags: php

I have page with 3 `$_GET` variables in the URL;

`http://www.example.co.uk/search?location=asokoro&day=today&time=12%3A00`

```
location = string, day = string, time = time eg 12:00, 13:15
```

I will like to prevent access to the page for the below conditions.

Prevent access if no variable received --- **COMPLETED**

```
if(!isset($_GET['location']) || !isset($_GET['day']) || !isset($_GET['time'])) {
    header("Location: http://www.example.co.uk");
    exit;
}
```

Prevent access if `location` is not supported --- **COMPLETED**

```
$locations = Array('loc1','loc2');
if (!in_array($_GET['location'], $locations)) {
    header("Location: http://www.example.co.uk");
    exit;
}
```

Prevent access if `day` is not correct--- **COMPLETED**

```
if($_GET['day'] != "today" || $_GET['day'] != "tomorrow") {
    header("Location: http://www.abklab.co.uk");
    exit;
}
```

Prevent access if `time` is not correct--- **NOT COMPLETED**

Here I want to be able to check if `time` is actually time and not some random string like `test`.

As you can see from the URL time is passed with `%3A` which reperents `:`
I would like to check if `time` is indeed a time eg 12:00, 14:20 etc if not then prevent access

Comment: Use php date (http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to get the time and compare against that.

Comment: Will it translate `%3A` to `:`?

Comment: you can use `regex` to check if time is actually time. This is the `regex` for time: `([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](:[0-5][0-9])?`

Comment: @Saani care to share the expression

Comment: edited my above comment already. Check it out!

Comment: `if ( $_GET['time'] !== date('H:i') ) { /* don't allow */ }` %3A should be automatically decoded for you.

Comment: @Saani Will it translate %3A to :?

Comment: `%3A` should be translated for you when you get the variable through `$_GET['time']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get the time variable through `$_GET['time']`, `%3A` should be translated to `:` and rest you can check if the `time` is actually `time` through `regex`. And the expression for that is: `([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](:[0-5][0-9])?`

Answer (score 0):

You just need a way to escape from html's special characters, right?
Try this:

```
if(strlen(trim($_GET['time'])) > 0){
    echo htmlspecialchars_decode(trim($_GET['time']));
}
```